# Associative array handling enum

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to print an associative array out in SystemVerilog.
I declared the base address and enum and expected the associative array will be:

```
UART1 : 32'h0a00_0000
UART2 : 32'h0a00_1000
UART3 : 32'h0a00_2000
UART4 : 32'h0a00_3000
```

but I get only a0000000.

```
test7.m_uart_base_addr[00]=a000000
test7.m_uart_base_addr[01]=a000000
test7.m_uart_base_addr[02]=a000000
test7.m_uart_base_addr[03]=a000000
```

How do I correctly get the associative array's enum values?
I implemented this in https://www.edaplayground.com/x/gjyk

This is my code.

```
`define NUM_OF_UART 4      
`define UART_BASE_ADDRESS 32'h0A00_0000      
`define UART_ADDRESS_RANGE 16'h0000  
                           
typedef enum {UART1, UART2, UART3, UART4} ip_idx_e;                                                              
                           
class test7_c;              
  rand ip_idx_e ip_idx;    
  rand int temp; //can't unique.    
  rand int arr[];         
                           
  bit[31:0] m_uart_base_addr[ip_idx_e];      
                                                                  
  function int my_rand();                
    return std::randomize(arr) with {    
      unique {arr};                      
      arr.size() inside {[1:10]};        
      arr.sum() inside {[0:100]};        
                   
      foreach(arr[i]) {
        arr[i] > 1;
        arr[i] < 100;
      }            
                   
    };              
  endfunction      
                   
  function void my_print();
    foreach(arr[i])
    $display("arr[%02d]=%02d", i, arr[i]);
  endfunction                                                    
endclass                                 
                   
module dut;        
                   
test7_c test7;    
                   
initial begin      
    test7 = new();                         
    test7.ip_idx = test7.ip_idx.first();
                   
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) begin
      test7.m_uart_base_addr[test7.ip_idx] = (`UART_BASE_ADDRESS) + (i * (`UART_ADDRESS_RANGE));
      $display("test7.m_uart_base_addr[%02h]=%02h" ,i ,test7.m_uart_base_addr[i]);
      if(test7.ip_idx != test7.ip_idx.last())
        test7.ip_idx = test7.ip_idx.next();
    end                            
end                                                              
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix it is to change:

```
`define UART_ADDRESS_RANGE 16'h0000
```

to:

```
`define UART_ADDRESS_RANGE 16'h1000
```

I  also get a warning message when I run the code:

```
      $display("test7.m_uart_base_addr[%02h]=%02h", i, test7.m_uart_base_addr[i]);
                                                                              |
xmelab: *W,ENUMERR : This assignment is a violation of SystemVerilog strong typing rules for enumeration datatypes.
```

This change gets rid of the warning:

```
  $display("test7.m_uart_base_addr[%02h]=%02h", i, test7.m_uart_base_addr[ test7.ip_idx ]);
```

This is the output I get:

```
test7.m_uart_base_addr[00]=a000000
test7.m_uart_base_addr[01]=a001000
test7.m_uart_base_addr[02]=a002000
test7.m_uart_base_addr[03]=a003000
```

If you want to print the enum names instead of numerical index values, you can use the `name()` method:

```
$display(
    "test7.m_uart_base_addr[%s]=%02h",
    test7.ip_idx.name(),
    test7.m_uart_base_addr[ test7.ip_idx ]
);
```

This prints:

```
test7.m_uart_base_addr[UART1]=a000000
test7.m_uart_base_addr[UART2]=a001000
test7.m_uart_base_addr[UART3]=a002000
test7.m_uart_base_addr[UART4]=a003000
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the line:

`` test7.m_uart_base_addr[test7.ip_idx] = (`UART_BASE_ADDRESS) + (i * (`UART_ADDRESS_RANGE)); ``

If `UART_ADDRESS_RANGE` is 0 all items in your associative array will be equal to `UART_BASE_ADDRESS`